# Close GPRS connection that was opened by another application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm developing an application that in the event of losing connectivity restarts the phone.

Before this step we'd like to close any open connections through Connection Manager. I understand we can use [ConnMgrReleaseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416503.aspx) to release a connection but is it possible to get the Connection handle if the connection was established through another application?

If connection manager fails to close the connection we can then perform a RASHangup but we'd like to attempt it through ConnectionManager first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no way to do it through connection amanger. The handle `ConnMgrReleaseConnection` wants is the one returned from the call to [`ConnMgrEstablishConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416567.aspx).  Presumably the "other" application called this and has the handle, but even if that app could give you the handle, it would be invalid in your own process space anyway.

Generally it would be bad form to do something like this anyway, as I'd assume that the app that openened the connection would expect it to always be open once it had asked for it.  Forcibly closing it (even through RAS) without that app knowing could lead to unexpected behavior. Probably not a huge issue for you if you're just going to restart the phone, but if you have any sort of control over that other app, I'd add handling where you can tell it to close it's connections.

Comment: I thought that was the case but hoped it wasn't. The other application is ours but this is a standalone application to handle a very rarely occurring issue. We are not actually restarting the device but turning radio on and off.

Comment: I'd implement a system named event then. Have the other app periodically check for the event (either in a timer or a worker thread) and have it release the connection when you assert the event.

Comment: You can use message windows to inform the other application to close the connection.

Comment: Let's say we have an application that runs every x minutes to monitor connectivity...If this apps detects no connectivity and establishes a connection using ConnMgrEstablishConnection but then closes and schedules itself to run again using CeRunAppAtTime then neither the same application running x minutes later or any other application will be able to close that connection using Connection Manager? I ask as I'm aware there are issues with performing a RASHangup if connection manager is not informed that the connection is closing.

Comment: When the app closes, the handle passes back from ConnMgrEstablishConnection becomes invalid, even if you're scheduled to run again.  Your request for a conenction is then "cancelled" and connection manager would decrement the connection reference count.  When that count hits zero, Connection Manager may (depending on the rules set) close the physical connection.  It also might just cache it for a while - it all depends on what it's been told to do.  A scheduled connection might give you more flexibility in keeping it "always on".